# Client side for formset django with jquery

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

Im trying to do a Formset with django, I dont have any problem with the process to save data, Im having problems with the client side. I mean, with the add button and remove button with Jquery. Specifically, because I need that detect when left one field does not show "remove" button. Clone an id in the DOM with Jquery would be easy, but my problem is honestly I dont know how works the names for each fields with formset.

My Forms.py

```
class FieldsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Fields
            fields = '__all__'

    FieldsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Form, Fields,extra=1,form=FieldsForm,can_delete=True)
```

My template:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<form method="post" action="#">{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
</form>
```

Comment: And you definitely don't want to use django-dynamic-formset?
 https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Comment: That plugin it's a good solution but  I have found some limitations, for example I don't have how to control when left one field and hide the delete button. I already asked in issues in Github but no one have answered.

Comment: still not sure I understand your problem but try adding  parameter  min_num=1 to your inlineformset_factory